# Сортировка числового массива .sort()

Tags: javascript, native

Необходимо отсортировать массив на нативном JS. Код:

```js
var inputStr = '235 1 0.9 -5 -98 25 -634.1';
var nArr;

function getConverArray(arr) {
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = +arr[i];
 }
 return arr;
}

nArr = getConverArray(inputStr.split(' '));

alert(nArr);
nArr.sort();
alert(nArr);
```

`.sort()` всё равно сортирует массив как символьный, хотя после функции `getConverArray()` массив становится числовым. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> По умолчанию, метод `sort` сортирует значения как строки в алфавитном
>   порядке, по возрастанию.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

Про

```
nArr.sort(function(a, b){ return a-b; });
```

Вы, скорее всего, знаете.

Пример из  [Проблемма с сортировкой массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826489/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/826491#)

```js
function median(data) {
  data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return data;
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
```

Answer (score 1):

.sort в любом случае сортирует массив как строку. Если нужно изменить его поведение, то нужно использовать функцию определяющую порядок сортировки.

Подробнее можно посмотреть в любом описании метода sort, а рабочий пример есть ниже.

```js
var inputStr = '235 1 0.9 -5 -98 25 -634.1';
var nArr;

nArr = inputStr.split(' ');

alert(nArr);
nArr.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });
alert(nArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputStr = [5, 2, 1, -10, 8];

function compare(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

inputStr.sort(compare);

console.log(inputStr);
```

и в обратном порядке:

```js
var inputStr = [5, 2, 1, -10, 8];

function compare(a, b) {
  return b - a;
}

inputStr.sort(compare);

console.log(inputStr);
```