# Проблемма с сортировкой массива

Tags: javascript

Получается в чём проблемма, у меня почему-то метод .sort() не сортирует последний 6-ти значный массив. В чём может быть проблемма?

```js
function median(data) {
//    var count = 0;
    x = data;
    x.sort();


//
//    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
//        if (data.length === 5 || data.length === 3) {
//            data.pop();
//            data.shift();
//        } else if (data.length === 6 || data.length === 4) {
//            data.pop();
//            data.shift();
//        }
//        if (data.length === 2) {
//            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
//                count = (data[0] + data[1]);
//                return count / 2;
//            }
//        }
//    }








    return data;
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сортировка по умолчанию срaвнивает элементы массива как строки. Js смотрит на пару, например, `100, 99` как на `"100", "99"` - в этом случае `"100"` меньше, чем `"99"`.

```js
function median(data) {
  data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return data;
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
```

Comment: Ну ты ж уже дважды отвечал на такой же вопрос

Comment: Черт возьми, это ж я уже отвечал ).

Comment: **дважды** !!! каждый год считай :-)

Comment: @Grundy Год - за два.

Comment: @Igor Хотел бы задать вопрос, а в каком смысле "Сортировка по умолчанию срaвнивает элементы массива как строки." Просто в массиве ведь числа.

Comment: @BraFik Js смотрит на пару, например, `100, 99` как на `"100", "99"` - в этом случае `"100"` меньше, чем `"99"`.

Comment: @Grundy, ты кладезь  информации по вопросам `JS`...)))